# How do I write a script that writes scripts if a file has the .iso extention in linux?

Tags: bash, file, if-statement

So I'm trying to make executables for games with an .iso extention, so I can add them to steam directly, but I didn't feel like writing every individual one manually, so I wrote a script to do it for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$/media/dexterdy/d60690f8-0511-44bf-aa66-b8a211460113/samsung/gamecube/"; do
    if [ ${file: -4} == ".iso" ]
    then
        cat > ${file}.sh << EOF
        dolphin-emu --batch --exec="/media/dexterdy/d60690f8-0511-44bf-aa66-b8a211460113/samsung/gamecube/${file}"
EOF
    fi
done;
```

If I run it, I don't get any error messages, but it also doesn't generate any files. I think it has to do with the if statement `([ ${file: -4} == ".iso" ])`, but I'm not sure. It could also be because the .iso files have spaces in their names.

P.S. I'm new to writing scripts and coding in general. This is my second script I've ever written, so it would be appreciated if the explanations aren't too complicated.

Comment: Add a `*` glob at the end of the directory before the `;` but outside the quotes in the for loop, e.g. `/samsung/gamecube/"*; do`

Comment: Or if you're jjust interested on files that ends with `.iso` it can be done like `/samsung/gamecube/"*.iso; do`

Comment: @dexterdyKrataigos: _I think it has to do with the if statement_  This too, but in the first place it rather has to do with the fact that your variable `file` does not hold the path to a file, but to the directory containing the files. The directory ends in `..../gameube`, and hence does not have an `iso` in the end.

Comment: Aha thank all for the input. I've gotten it to work now!